# Corona SDK Lag on All Devices?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, coronasdk

I've been using Corona SDK for a little over a year at work now, and one thing that I've noticed is that there is a significant lack of 'smoothness'. I've used it to make a range of games and business apps, and anything that has to do with animation of some sort (ScrollView, TableView, Transitions etc.) never runs smoothly compared to, say, a ScrollView in native iOS development.

Does anyone else experience this? At first, I thought it might have been my code's fault, but after creating a plain project with only a ScrollView widget and it still lagging, I really didn't know what to do anymore. I've also tested it on multiple devices, including the iPhone 6, iPad Air and Samsung Galaxy S3.

Now, my main question is if there is anything I can do to make these widgets and transitions run more smoothly. I personally love the productivity I have when using Corona and the last thing I'd want to do is to abandon it, but it really is quite embarrassing when you're dealing with a client and they utter an unimpressed "mmh okay" because the app just doesn't run as well as it should!

Comment: Are you running at 30 fps or 60 fps?

Comment: I'm not sure; how do I check?

Comment: It would be defined in your config.lua.  If it's not, the default is 30 fps.